# How to run cron once a day at midnight

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I want to run a cron once a day at midnight so have added this command to crontab -e.

```
00 00 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/../public_html/bin/magento cron:run --group="crongroup"
```

but not sure what values should use for these fields

```
<group id="crongroup">

<schedule_generate_every>5</schedule_generate_every>

<schedule_ahead_for>10</schedule_ahead_for>

<schedule_lifetime>5</schedule_lifetime>

<history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>

<history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>

<history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
```

Please let me know which values need to be change in the above code so that cron can run every night without being missed.

Comment: 0 0 * * *.    try this

Answer (score 3):

Checkout https://crontab.guru/, you can find out how to correctly configure your cronjobs